# Radon Nikodym and Lebesgue monotone convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So, I've been trying to prove 2 excersises with bad luck so far, they go like:

I.
Assume that $(X,M,\mu)$ is a space with $\sigma$-finite measure, $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, signed measure. Show that:

$1^\circ$ $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^+}{d\mu}-\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^-}{d\mu}$

$2^\circ$ $\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)^+=\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^+}{d\mu}$ and $ \left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)^-=\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^-}{d\mu}$.

II. Assume that $(X,M,\mu)$ is a space with measure, $E\in M$, $f_n:E \to (0,\infty]$

$1^\circ$ Show that if series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_Ef_nd\mu$ converges, then series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ is converging $\mu$-almost everywhere.

$2^\circ$ Show that if integrals $\int_Ef_nd\mu$ for nautral $n$ are finite, and sequence $(\int_Ef_nd\mu)_n$ is bounded, then for any converging series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ with non negative values, series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nf_n$ is converging $\mu$-almost everywhere.

While trying to get I,$1^\circ$ done I tried to chose $E\in M$ and defined $f=f_1-f_2$, $\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^+}{d\mu}=\int_Ef_1d\mu$ and $\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^-}{d\mu}=\int_Ef_2d\mu$ from there I wrote:

$\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\int_Ef_d\mu=\int_Ef_1-f_2d\mu=\int_Ef_1d\mu-\int_Ef_2d\mu=\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^+}{d\mu}-\frac{d\left(\nu\right)^-}{d\mu}$

For I,$2^\circ$ I tried to define $\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)^+=max(\int_Efd\mu,0)$ and $ \frac{d\left(\nu\right)^+}{d\mu}=\int_Emax(f,0)d\mu$ ending up with two possibilities.

For II,$1^\circ$ I tried to use LMCT and got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n=\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ and wrote that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int f_n$ is convergent then $\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ is aswell.

For II,$2^\circ$ I wrote that if $\int_Ef_nd\mu$ is finite and its sequence is restricted then $\forall_n \exists_M |\int_Ef_nd\mu|<M$ and so $\forall_N \exists_M |f_n|<M$ $\mu$-almost everywhere and finally wrote: $\sum a_nf_n\leq\sum a_n|f_n|\leq\sum a_n M=M\sum a_n$ which I fought is the end of the proof.

Profesor didn't like any of those answers but I'm not sure what are the mistakes or how to repair them.